# inductive return: Breaking a reccursion

Tags: python

I am implementing a recursive algorithm:

```
def induct(arg):
    if doStuff(arg) == 0:
        return # Completely stop algorithm, go home.

    induct(doStuff(arg))
```

The problem is that `return` will only return the *current* call of `induct`. Is there a way to return all `induct` calls to completely halt the algorithm?

Comment: Possible through hacks, but it would be probably be cleaner if you could change the algorithm to avoid that.

Comment: converting your recursion to an iteration could solve your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raise an exception instead of return.

Comment: Raising an exception is very different than halting the algorithm. In any case, that isn't necessary with this problem

Comment: @DavidRobinson not true. How do you think generators indicate that they are exhausted and that iteration should halt? They raise an exception (`StopIteration`).

Comment: I don't know how that's related. What I meant with my comment is that if someone is just calling the function induct, they a) might not want to encase it in a try/except, and b) might want to return a value. The fact that it's possible to use exceptions to halt other processes has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 2):

In the case you cite, that return statement *will* return all calls of induct and the algorithm will be halted.

ETA: This is true in any [tail-recursive function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).

Comment: Perhaps you could post your actual code rather than this example? In the example you post, the moment return is called, it will return every function all the way up the stack.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a `return` before the recursive call:

```
def induct(arg):
    if doStuff(arg) == 0:
        return # Completely stop algorithm, go home.

    return induct(doStuff(arg))
```